# Log long-running transactions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting "Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded" errors in my production Rails app, and I'm looking for help debugging which transaction is locking the tables for an excessively long time. MySQL has a "slow query" log, but not a log of slow transactions, as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to log information about how long transactions take directly from ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 4):

My team logs slow transactions like this:

In `lib/slow_transaction_logger.rb`:

```
module SlowTransactionLogger
  LOG_IF_SLOWER_THAN_SECONDS = ENV.fetch("LOG_TRANSACTIONS_SLOWER_THAN_SECONDS", "5").to_f

  def transaction(*args)
    start = Time.now
    value = super
    finish = Time.now

    duration = finish - start

    return value if duration <= LOG_IF_SLOWER_THAN_SECONDS

    backtrace = caller.
      select { |path| path.start_with?(Rails.root.to_s) }.
      reject { |row|
        row.include?("/gems/") ||
        row.include?("/app/middleware/") ||
        row.include?("/config/initializers/")
      }

    puts "slow_transaction_logger: duration=#{duration.round(2)} start=#{start.to_s.inspect} finish=#{finish.to_s.inspect} class=#{name} caller=#{backtrace.to_json}"

    value
  end
end
```

In `config/initializers/active_record.rb`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    prepend SlowTransactionLogger
  end
end
```

So by default, it logs transactions slower than 5 seconds, in every environment.

If you set a `LOG_TRANSACTIONS_SLOWER_THAN_SECONDS` environment variable (e.g. on Heroku), you can tweak that limit.

We log with `puts` intentionally because it ends up in the logs in Heroku, and we also we see it more easily in dev and tests. But feel free to use `Rails.logger` if you prefer.